# jssor arrow outside the picture frame

Tags: page-layout, layout

I'm starting to use the Jssor Slider (slideshow builder), and I wonder if there's a way to place the arrows outside the frame of the pictures (for example, at both sides or under the frame).

Comment: This question might be more suitable for [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: @zeethreepio, Stack Overflow is for developer, for designer, it's better to ask question on this site.

Comment: Seeing as Jssor Slider is a JQuery image carousel, I figured one would need to know a fair bit of code to troubleshoot this question - this is what I mean by more suitable for SO. It also doesn't quite fit the topics as outlined in the [Help Center](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for this site so I was merely trying to steer the OP in the right direction in getting the answer they need.

Comment: @zeethreepio thank you! stack overflow is for developer only. our software are for both designer and developer.

Comment: @zeethreepio you know, designers are not familiar with coding, and our software requires no coding skill, so this site is more suitable for design question. We direct designer to this site and developer to stack overflow. Thank you so much! See http://www.jssor.com/support.html

Comment: @zeethreepio Please checkout http://www.jssor.com/demos/tutorial/presentation.slider/=edit, It's design work, not coding work. Thank you so much!

Comment: @jssor, I strongly disagree with the statement "designers are not familiar with coding". There is often a huge gray area between the two disciplines and you'd be foolish to segregate design from coding and vice versa. You would also be selling yourself short in this industry by not knowing coding. Nevertheless, I've been playing around with the Jssor Slider and I can agree it's appropriate for this site. I'm guessing by your username that you may have had a part in developing so I understand and appreciate your time defending the product.

Comment: @zeethreepio I don't think designers of flash, PPT, google slide, prezi know coding well. Some of them just need to design and show their presentation, they don't need code. Questions apart from coding will be rejected on stackoverflow. As I know, no coding html design services are expanding quickly. With the services, users design a page and share link on facebook, wechat etc. They don't need code and don't even know what does code standfor.

Comment: @zeethreepio Not sure if you know slideshow services like animoto, smilebox. I don't think people should learn coding before creating family slideshow, wedding slideshow and album. And for ad designers, they don't need to know coding neither.

Comment: @jssor, I don't think you can consider casual users making the occasional slideshow for the family gathering "designers." Quite frankly, that's rather insulting. You're also painting with a broad brush assuming that designers don't know how to code (and ad designers  - the good ones - can indeed). Let's agree to disagree, but from my experience I've found coding to be an extremely valuable skill in the design industry. If you have any further comments you can message me directly in chat, this conversation has gone on too long for this site's format.

Comment: @zeethreepio You are defending that designer comes with good coding skill. But objectively, you discriminate against none coders and block them from using software they need. No more comments here, I am moving out.

Comment: @zeethreepio Sure I can't assuming, I just write down what I see in the market. And you have no rights to determine what kind of skill should have to use what kind of software neither.

Comment: @jssor, I'm not discriminating against non-coding designers (I used to be one myself), I'm merely making the point that many designers in the market today do write code and it's smart to have a working knowledge of it. I also never attempted to determine which type of software is deemed appropriate for any designer at any skill level. Your comments are twisting my words and seem to be a bit misinformed when it comes to the skill level of professional designers in the industry. I'm not exactly sure where the animosity is stemming from here. Best of luck.

Comment: @zeethreepio It seems you are still interested in this topic. Let me post my point here. With jssor slider make, users should have lots of non-coding questions in design area. Obviously these questions are not suitable for stackoverflow. I am wondering which site is appropriate for these questions.

Answer (score 0):

Given the width of your picture is 500.
You can set the width of outer container to 800.
Then you have chance to place arrows outside of picture.

[image: jssor slider arrows outside of picture area]